# Regex expression to find number sequence?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex to return the ticket number from the following body of text:

```
TICKET #IM40135514 OPENED
```

In this case, would return

```
IM40133514
```

I am not sure what the proper regex expression would be. I tried

```
number=re.findall("TICKET (\w{2}d{7}+))", filetext)
```

but keep getting an error.

Comment: `keep getting an error` You should edit your question and include the text of the full error.

Comment: Do all ticket numbers have to letters followed by eight digits? If so, are the letters always `"IM"`? If not necessarily `"IM"` is it always two capital letters at the beginning? Can the digits begin with a zero? Please answer by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.findall` should be fine here:

```py
inp = "TICKET #IM40135514 OPENED"
nums = re.findall(r'\bTICKET #(\S+)', inp)
print(nums)  #['IM40135514']
```

Note that I am using a raw string for the regex pattern, which is indicated with a prefix of `r`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not required here. You can just `split()` the text by a space, grab the middle string, and remove the "#".

```
s = "TICKET #IM40135514 OPENED"
ticket = s.split()[1].replace("#", "")
print(ticket)
```

and the ticket # is returned,

```
IM40135514
```

Comment: If you are confident that all lines are formatted correctly, as in your example, you could remove what you don't want rather than extract what you do want: `re.sub(r'TICKET #| OPENED', '', s) ->  "IM40135514"`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong with your expression.

1. Unless using a raw string, you'll need to double escape so that the regex engine gets the full escape sequence. `r"\w"` is equivalent to `"\\w"`.
2. You're missing  a # in your expression.
3. You need to escape the d in `\w{2}\d{7}`.
4. The + means it repeats one or more times and doesn't compile after `{7}` like that.

Recommend using regex101.com to build your expressions as it breaks them down and explains them to you.

The expression `r"TICKET #(\w{2}\d{7})"` closely matches what you had and might work for you. Note that `\w` matches numbers as well so if you specifically want letters, you can use `[a-zA-Z]{2}`.